# How to create folder based on first and second part of file name and move files into the folder?

Tags: batch-file

I created the following batch script to create a folder based on today's date and then group files into folders based on the file name.

For example the files

```
JIM_BRICKMAN_QPS.avi
JIM_BRICKMAN_Slice.avi
JIM_BRICKMAN_Slice.jpg
```

are moved to the folder `BRICKMAN`.

This works fine, however, attempts to modify the batch file to move the newly created folders into the newly created date folder fail or overwrite the folders when going through the loop.

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/" %%A in ('date /t') do (
    set DateDay=%%A
    set DateMonth=%%B
    set DateYear=%%C
)
set CurrentDate=%DateDay%-%DateMonth%-%DateYear%
if not exist "%CurrentDate%" md %CurrentDate%

for %%A in (*.avi *.jpg) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%D in ("%%~nA") do (
        md "%%D" 2>nul
        echo Moving file %%A to folder %%D
        move "%%A" "%%D" >nul
    )
)

echo Finished
```

Additionally, I can't seem to get the token to ignore the first delimiter so that the folder is titled `JIM_BRICKMAN` and not just `BRICKMAN`.

**EDIT:**

I rewrote the batch file after the suggestions in the comments:

```
set "CurrentDate=%DATE:~-10,2%-%DATE:~-7,2%-%DATE:~-4%"
if not exist "%CurrentDate%" md %CurrentDate%
for %%A in (*.avi *.jpg) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%D_%%E in ("%%~nA") do (
        md "%%D_%%E" 2>nul
        move "%%A" "%%D_%%E" >nul
    )
)
```

But the script seems to bomb out. I tried to capture the error, but it closes despite me putting **PAUSE** in the script.

Comment: I find it always interesting to see code using command `date /t` in a batch file although there are the built-in environment variables `DATE` and `TIME` to reference the current date and time in localized format. Run `set /?` in a command prompt window and read all help pages including the last one listing the built-in variables. Run `echo %DATE%` and `echo %TIME%` or `echo %DATE% %TIME%` to see that those environment variables really exist and how date/time format is on your computer with your account according to your Windows Region and Language settings.

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `for /?` to get displayed the help for this command explaining also the options for `for /F`. To get just `BRICKMAN` assigned to loop variable `D` you need `for /F "tokens=2 delims=_" %%D in ("%%~nA") do (`, i.e. `tokens=2` instead of `tokens=1,*`.

Comment: @Mofi, `date /T` and `echo %DATE%` usually return the same string; but `time /T` and `echo %TIME%` do not; the former returns hour and minute only, but the latter returns seconds and centiseconds too...

Comment: @aschipfl That difference between `echo %TIME%` and `time /T` is well known by me. However, current second and centisecond are usually not needed in batch files. Most often just the date is needed and no time at all. So usually it is enough to use something like `set "FolderDate=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~-7,2%-%DATE:~-10,2%"` to get with local date format `DD[./-]MM[./-]YYYY` with or without weekday at beginning the date in format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Running `date /t` in a background cmd process by __FOR__ is much slower although for a human usually not noticeable slower than a simple string substitution.

Comment: @Mofi I can get BRICKMAN but I want to get JIM_BRICKMAN.

Comment: @GerardRodriguez For `JIM_BRICKMAN` use `"tokens=1,2 delims=_"` and use `%%D_%%E` instead of just `%%D` within __FOR__ loop.

Comment: @Mofi I implemented your suggestion but the script seems to bomb out. I tried to capture the error but it closes despite me putting "PAUSE" in the script. 
    set "CurrentDate=%DATE:~-10,2%-%DATE:~-7,2%-%DATE:~-4%"
    if not exist "%CurrentDate%" md %CurrentDate%

    for %%A in (*.avi *.jpg) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%D_%%E in ("%%~nA") do (
       md "%%D_%%E" 2>nul
   move "%%A" "%%D_%%E" >nul
    ))

Comment: Thanks for the run down! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double clicking on a batch file in development is no good idea because this results in starting

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c "batch file name with full path and extension"
```

As it can be read on running `cmd /?` from within a command prompt window, the option `/C` means **close** the command process and its console window immediately after execution of command, executable or script finished independent on the reason for ending the execution.

For debugging a batch file in development it is much better to

1. open a command prompt window,
2. change the current directory with command **CD** to directory of batch file and
3. run the batch file by typing its name and hitting key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

For batch files which should work independent on which directory is the current directory, it is advisable to omit point 2 and run the batch file with entering its full path, file name and file extension enclosed in double quotes with current directory being not the directory of the batch file.

A batch file is executed from within a command prompt window with:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /K BatchFileNameAsTyped
```

The option `/K` means **keep** command process running which results in keeping also command prompt window opened after execution of command/executable/script which makes it possible to read error messages.

The keys <kbd>UP ARROW</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd> can be used to reload command lines once entered in command prompt window making it easy to run the batch file once again after making a modification in GUI text editor.

And with having `@echo off` removed from first line of batch file, or changed to `@echo ON`, or commented out this line with command **REM** or with `::` (invalid label) at beginning, it is also possible to see which lines Windows command interpreter really executes after applying immediate environment variable expansion and where an error occurs in case of a syntax error.

---

Wrong on second batch code is the line:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%D_%%E in ("%%~nA") do (
```

Specified as loop variable must be always 1 character. Right would be:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%D in ("%%~nA") do (
```

---

The command `echo %DATE%` outputs on my computer with my account and my region settings today the date `01.04.2017`.

The command `echo %DATE:~-10,2%-%DATE:~-7,2%-%DATE:~-4%` outputs `01-04-2017`.

So this part of the script works.

**Hint:** A list of directories in format `YYYY-MM-DD` is better than in format `DD-MM-YYYY`. The list of directories with format `YYYY-MM-DD` sorted alphabetically as by default is automatically with this date format also sorted from oldest to newest. Date format `DD-MM-YYYY` results in a weird list of the directories on being sorted alphabetically as by default.

---

A batch file for this task could be:

```
@echo off
set "CurrentDate=%DATE:~-10,2%-%DATE:~-7,2%-%DATE:~-4%"
for %%A in (*.avi *.jpg) do (
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%D in ("%%~nA") do (
        if not "%%E" == "" (
            md "%CurrentDate%\%%D_%%E" 2>nul
            move /Y "%%A" "%CurrentDate%\%%D_%%E\"
        ) else (
            md "%CurrentDate%\%%D" 2>nul
            move /Y "%%A" "%CurrentDate%\%%D\"
        )
    )
)
set "CurrentDate="
```

How the inner loop works is most interesting for this task.

`for /F` and `"%%~nA"` means the command **FOR** should process just the file name of the *.avi or *.jpg file without file extension found by outer **FOR** loop.

`delims=_` means the **FOR** command should split up the string into multiple parts (tokens) using underscore as delimiter. The first file name is `JIM_BRICKMAN_QPS` which would be split up to:

1. `JIM` assigned to loop variable `D` being specified in **FOR** command line,
2. `BRICKMAN` assigned to loop variable `E` which is the next character in [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) after `D` and
3. `QPS` assigned to loop variable `F`.

This string split feature is the reason why loop variables are interpreted case-sensitive while environment variables are interpreted not case-sensitive.

With `tokens=1,2` is specified that just first and second string parts are of interest. So inner **FOR** can stop string splitting after having already determined the first two underscore delimited strings and having assigned them to the loop variables `D` and `E`.

**FOR** executes the command block if it could determine at least 1 string delimited by an underscore. So it is possible that loop variable `D` has a string value, but loop variable `E` is an empty string, for example if the file name does not contain any underscore. That is the reason for the **IF** condition.

The command **MD** creates with command extensions enabled as by default the entire directory tree. Therefore it is not necessary to create the date subdirectory explicitly before searching for *.avi and *.jpg files. That is good as it avoids creating empty date directories when there are no *.avi and *.jpg files in current directory.

As the *.avi and *.jpg files in current directory should be moved to `DD-MM-YYYY\Token1_Token2` it is of course necessary to specify also the environment variable with todays date string on creating the directory and moving the file.

The error message output by **MD** if the directory exists (or when it fails to create the directory because of missing permissions) to handle **STDERR** is redirected with `2>nul` to device **NUL** to suppress it.

The **MOVE** command is used with option `/Y` to move the file to target folder even if the current file exists already in target folder.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).