# Automatically Create Folders Based on String in Filename

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file to create a process for a large list (2k) of TIF files in a local folder directory.

The filename structure is, for example: 12345_1.tif.

I need the batch to:

1 - Create a folder name based on the number(s) after the underscore, as this is the only constant in the naming. The folders only based on this sole number.

2 - Copy and move the file into the newly created folder.

In the example above, the batch would create a folder called 1 and then move the file 12345_1.tif into that folder. If it found another file such as 54321_1.tif, that file would also be moved to the "1" folder. In my files, the numbers after the _ range from 1 through 77, and there could multiple files that share the same number after the _.

I've observed some similar scripts online, but I need help to modify my requirement. Is it possible to modify this to meet my requirement?

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.PDF') do (
    set "filename1=%%~i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "folder1=!filename1:~11,6!"
    mkdir "!folder1!" 2>nul
    move "!filename1!" "!folder1!"
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create folder based on first and second part of file name and move files into the folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109253/how-to-create-folder-based-on-first-and-second-part-of-file-name-and-move-files)

Comment: Thanks, but the cited posted talks of using the current date in the batch process. I have no interest in using the date for my folders.

Comment: Simpler: `for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /B *.tif') do (` and `md %%b 2>NUL` and `move %%a_%%b.tif %%b` and `)`

Comment: It also has to do with using part of the filename to create a folder and move the file into that folder. It's your task to take the code from that post (which answers your question) and adapt it to your situation. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your comment - I'm new to SO - and still learning how to manipulate BAT files for my personal data pre-processing needs - I had no expectation of this being a "code writing service" I have managed IT dev projects in past careers, so I have a respect for what developers do...I thought the purpose of SO is to  "to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming" - From https://stackoverflow.com/about thanks for the warm welcome ;)

Comment: @Aacini Thanks for your post. I tried your version, but cmd just runs and show the following directory name for all the files. It runs through all 2K images but does not create the corresponding folder or move the files, since no folder is created.                                                           
                                                                                                  
  (my DIR)  and then '\datasets\train>(and md 2  and move 99822_2.tif 2 and  2>NUL )'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you didn't understood [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367658/automatically-create-folders-based-on-string-in-filename#comment93612754_53367658), so I post it here as an answer with complete code:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /B *.tif') do (
   md "%%b" 2>NUL
   move "%%a_%%b.tif" "%%b"
)
```

Comment: This was crucial; this complete code worked this time - any 101 resources you can recommend for learning BAT commands?

Comment: What do you mean by "this time"? This is the _exact same code_ I posted in my comment, where each `part over blue background` indicate one line in the Batch file...

Comment: May I ask you to select this one as Best Answer? You may also upvote it when you can...Thanks!