# batch create folders & move, exclude files without string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367658/automatically-create-folders-based-on-string-in-filename) to batch create folders & move files based on file names. My files are  TIFs, with this naming schema:

12345_001.tif
12345_002.tif
12345_003.tif
12346_001.tif
12346_002.tif
12347.tif
12348.tif

My code:

```
    @echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /B *.tif') do (
   md "%%a" 2>NUL
   move "%%a_%%b.tif" "%%a"
)
```

Some files in the folder don't have number suffixes. When I run the script, it creates folders for everything, even empty ones for the files without numbers after the underscore. So I end up with this in my source dir:
12345 (folder)
12346 (folder)
12347 (empty folder)
12348 (empty folder)
12347.tif
12348.tif

How can I get it to skip creating folders for the items without numbers after the underscore? I'm sure there is something simple, but I haven't worked with bat files before this.

Comment: `if not  "%%b" == "" ...`

Comment: Then use `dir /B *_*.tif` instead of just `dir /B *.tif` to process only `.tif` files having at least one underscore in file name as that is what your `for /F` loop expects. BTW: Better would be `for /F "eol=|delims=" %%I in ('dir *_*.tif /A-D-H-R /B 2^>nul') do for /F "eol=| delims=_" %%J in ("%%I") do md "%%J" 2>nul & move /Y "%%I" "%%J\"` which works also for very unusual file names like `;12349___12&test!_yeah().tif` or `_12345__342.tif`.

Comment: It would be also possible to use __FINDSTR__ as filter like with using `for /F "eol=| tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%I in ('dir *_*.tif /A-D-H-R /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /X "[0123456789][0123456789]*_[0123456789][0123456789]*\.tif"') do md "%%I" 2>nul & move /Y "%%I_%%J" "%%I\"` which processes only files of which name has case-insensitive interpreted the file extension `.tif` (and so excludes `.tiff` which `dir` does not exclude) containing exactly one underscore between two numbers each with at least one digit.

Comment: Using @Mofi 's first answer worked with dir /B *_*.tif since these all use the same schema and there aren't any outliers. Saving this so I can use the expanded version in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is reasonably straightforward in PowerShell.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*_*.tif' |
    ForEach-Item {
        if ($_.Name -match '^(\d*)_.*') {
            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $Matches[1])) { mkdir $Matches[1] | Out-Null }
            mv $_.FullName $Matches[1]
        }
    }
```

If it must run from cmd.exe, some readability is to be sacrificed.

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*_*.tif' |" ^
        "ForEach-Item {" ^
            "if ($_.Name -match '^(\d*)_.*') {" ^
                "if (-not (Test-Path -Path $Matches[1])) { mkdir $Matches[1] | Out-Null }" ^
                "mv $_.FullName $Matches[1]" ^
            "}" ^
        "}"
```

If you want to keep it as cryptic as the cmd.exe language, it could be done as a one-liner.

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "gci -file '*_*.tif'|%{if($_.Name -match '^(\d*)_.*') {mkdir $Matches[1]|Out-Null;mv $_.FullName $Matches[1]}}"
```